# Excel formula based on date variables

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, calculator

I'm trying to create a fee calculator but I can't seem to get the formulas to work for me. I'm essentially trying to write one long formula that takes into account all of the different date variables. I have six selectable products and I've been trying to use a combination of IF, AND and OR statements.

My columns are set up like this:

[image]

List of products:

Product 1

Product 2

Product 3

Product 4

Product 5

Product 6

I want the formula in C2 to return:

"No" under "Fee Payable" for the following:

- IF Product 5 or Product 6 are in A2, OR
- IF Product 3 OR 4 are in A2 AND the date in B2 is less than 18/12/2014, OR
- IF there is any product in A2 AND the date in B2 is less that 29/03/2012

"Yes" for the following:

- IF Products 3 or 4 are in A2 AND IF B2 is greater than or equal to 18/12/2014, OR
- IF Products 1 or 2 are in A2 AND IF B2 is greater than or equal to 29/03/2012

I would like C2 remain blank until something is entered into A2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing too creative here - just a brute force set of IF statements. Column C contains this formula filled down ...

`=IF(OR(A2=$E$6,A2=$E$7,AND(OR(A2=$E$4,A2=$E$5),B2<DATE(2014,12,18)),AND(A2<>"",B2<DATE(2012,3,29))),"No",IF(OR(AND(OR(A2=$E$4,A2=$E$5),B2>=DATE(2014,12,18)),AND(OR(A2=$E$2,A2=$E$3),B2>=DATE(2012,3,29))),"Yes",""))`

And generated these results. Note: I used Column E to hold a list of Valid Products. Note 2: Added test cases as per Scott's suggestion ...

[image]

Comment: Arguably, your answer presentation would be better if you added `A20`, `A21` and `A22` = "Product 7" (or something else not on the list) and `A23`, `A24` and `A25` = blank.  And, strictly speaking, you don't need the `$`s before the `E`s.  Otherwise, this answer is perfect.   P.S. I was using Fortran before 1977.

Comment: Thanks @Scott - `A20` and `A23` are non-trivial and should be shown. Updated the screen cap.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I would like to suggest improvise Formula which is smaller than previous.

[image]

The Reasons are,

**For NO**, Instead of testing product 5 & 6 with date and as OR test Product 3 and 4 separately, better we test them using One Single statement since is technically similar, better & reduces the length of Formula.

I’ve tested Products 3, 4, 5 & 6 with Date value **29/03/2012** coz if the Date is less than it means the Date is naturally smaller than **18/12/2014**.

And if A2 is Blank no need to Test further Coz, your last condition is if A2 blank C2 remain blank also,so that I’ve tested it at First.

Likewise I’ve tested **For YES**, Product 1, 2, 3 & 4 with date value **18/12/2014**, since if the date value in cell is either greater than or equals to it means is higher value date than **29/03/2012**.

**NB:** If you compare both results you find difference in Row 9 and 12. Reason is simple Date values in both the rows are greater than the date vales we are testing with.

Please change the Data Range in your Formula as your need.

My Data Range is I79:K99, Formula is in K79.

Sample Column is Product Name & Date to Match has data range M79:M88.
**Column is Green** holds answer produced by previous Formula.